# Fragment not getting replaced on re-entry

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabs, fragmentmanager

I've been stumped on this for two days now:

1 activity, 3 fragments (A, B and C). B and C are tabs. If I replace fragment A with B and add A to the back stack like so:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .addToBackStack("A_TO_B_TAG")
               .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, "FragmentB")
               .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
               .commit();
```

When I hit the up caret from Fragment C and do this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                //Pop the back stack and hide the Up caret
                FragmentManager fm = mHostingActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    fm.popBackStack();
                }
                mHostingActivity.getDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

                //Kill any tabs
                mHostingActivity.getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
                mHostingActivity.getSupportActionBar().removeAllTabs();


                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And then re-enter B with the first code snippet, **A's onPause() / onStop() is not called and both are drawn on-top of one-another**. Does anyone know what could cause this?

I have submitted a bug report because I am truly unsure as to why this behaviour is occurring, it is located [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71219&thanks=71219&ts=1402506255).

Comment: try fm.popBackStackImmediate();

Comment: Hmm I'm nearly certain the problem is not with the back stack. It works fine if I don't 'tabify' B and C. See I need Fragment A in the back stack (not B or C as they are tabs). Frag A won't stop drawing when I replace it with Frag B. It works fine the first time but not the second time I load Frag B.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can tell this is what's happening and if anyone ever stumbles across this problem I hope my answer is useful!

Re-entering a tabbed fragment i.e.:

add A -> replace A with tab B -> replacing B with tab C -> pop tab C -> and then replace A with tab B again

A is not detached when replaced with B for that last transition, so I have placed this in **Fragment A's onCreateView()**

```
        final FragmentManager fm = mHostingActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                    Fragment fragmentB = fm.findFragmentByTag("FragmentB");
                    Fragment fragmentC =  fm.findFragmentByTag("FragmentC");

                    if (fragmentB != null) {
                        //Hmm force detach here rather than when we pop via the up affordance
                        if (!fragmentB.isDetached())
                            fm.beginTransaction().detach(fragmentB).commit();
                    }
                    if (fragmentC != null) {
                        if (!fragmentC.isDetached())
                            fm.beginTransaction().detach(fragmentC).commit();
                    }

                    //Listened for any changes after re-entering the FragmentA so we can remove the listener
                    fm.removeOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
```

Meaning every-time fragment A is created we detach any of the tabbed fragments which erroneously may have not been detached.